# How to install packages in ubuntu without internet connection?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, package-management, dependencies, offline

I am using Ubuntu since last 2 years but still I couldnt find better way to install Ubuntu packages offline. As each package needs multiple dependencies its harder to find & get all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Cube](https://launchpad.net/camicricube)**. It is a portable package manager capable of downloading packages and list of latest repositories from other computers with internet connection (Linux or Windows), and installs it back to your original computer, offline.

Check [this tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583) on how it works.